# open light socket on string lights safe to use?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, bulb

I have string lights in my room and my sister accidentally broke one of the bulbs. The lights are my main source of light in my room so I was wondering if I just removed the broken bulb it would all be fine but I'm worried that if plug them in something bad will happen

Comment: Do these string lights take standard light bulbs?

Comment: I'm still unsure your meaning of string lights so you have to be descriptive as possible but if the bulbs screw out  and you took it out and now it doesn't work it means you need to replace the bulb or find a cheap lamp at a yard sale for light in your room.

Answer (score 1):

By string lights are you refering to something like a string of christmas lights. If this is what you mean then remove the buld and replace it. If you don't have a replacement bulb, cover the opening with tape just so nobody sticks their finger in the opening and you're good to go. Plug it in and let there be light.

Comment: or if they are series connected, let there be dark.